# Does python Cmd module have a greet/usage summary message?

Tags: python, cmd

I started using python Cmd module, and I would like it to print a greet message and/or a short command summary before beginning the input loop (so the user won't be totally lost).
Can it be done?

Comment: `cmdloop` takes an optional `intro` parameter to use as a greeting message.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html#cmd.Cmd.cmdloop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Cmd documentation for `cmdloop`:

> The optional argument is a banner or intro string to be issued before the first prompt (this overrides the intro class attribute).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Cmd.preloop()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/cmd.html#cmd.Cmd.preloop) and just print whatever you like with `print`